# pass id through on click react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my partial code but my question is very simple, how can I get says data-id="1" to my function when user clicked on the `li`?

```
render(){
    return(
      <ul id="todo">
      {this.state.items.map((item,i) => 
        <li className='list-group-item' key={i} data-id={item.id}>{item.name}
        <button onClick={//how to pass item.id to my function?}>X</button>
        </li>
      )}
      </ul>
    ) 
  }
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since you are already using ES6 - might be a little cleaner to use an [arrow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) function here:

```
render(){
    return(
      <ul id="todo">
      {this.state.items.map((item,i) => 
        <li className='list-group-item' key={i} data-id={item.id}>{item.name}
        <button onClick={() => this.yourfunc(item.id)}>X</button>
        </li>
      )}
      </ul>
    ) 
}
```

Comment: wow don't have to use bind? the this keyword in arrow function point to the function itself?

Comment: Nope. You do not have to use bind when using arrow functions. Definitely check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions for reference

Comment: Didn't know about this, I was giving myself a hard time by using functions within a component only to fire a function from the props and send some extra params.. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You can use `bind()` to do this.

```
render(){
    return(
      <ul id="todo">
      {this.state.items.map((item,i) => 
        <li className='list-group-item' key={i} data-id={item.id}>{item.name}
        <button onClick={yourfunc.bind(this, item.id)}>X</button>
        </li>
      )}
      </ul>
    ) 
  }
```

Your function will receive `item.id` as the first parameter

Answer (score 9):

In my opinion, you shouldn't declare functions, nor bind methods within *render* method. Neither of these:

`onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, item.id)}`

`onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, item.id)}`

I know it's plenty of tutoriales showing that syntax. But there's also a considerable number of blog posts warning about why that's not a good idea. Basically, you are creating a new function on each render.

Go check the manual:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

And I'm aware that in the last two examples *it does create functions on render*. But react manual also shows this example and says:

```
class LoggingButton extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    console.log('this is:', this);
  }

  render() {
    // This syntax ensures `this` is bound within handleClick
    return (
      <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

> The problem with this syntax is that a different callback is created
>   each time the LoggingButton renders. In most cases, this is fine.
>   However, if this callback is passed as a prop to lower components,
>   those components might do an extra re-rendering. We generally
>   recommend binding in the constructor or using the class fields syntax,
>   to avoid this sort of performance problem.

---

BETTER SOLUTION

So, if you only need to pass one value, then check out the other examples in the manual. Basically you can *bind* the method in the constructor (or use an experimental syntax to avoid that step).

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}
```

And how would you get the **id/value** that you are trying to get? See this example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick({currentTarget}) {    
    console.log(currentTarget.value) // e.currentTarget.value would be equivalent
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button value="here!" onClick={this.handleClick}>   
        Click me
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

So, if you are using buttons or any form element (accepting a **value**), you may definitively consider this syntax.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this as follows :

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
         super(props);
         this.state = {
            items: [
                {item: "item", id: 1},
                {item1: "item1", id: 2}
            ]
         }
    }

    handleClick(id, e){
        alert(id);
    }

    render(){
        return(
           <ul id="todo">
               {this.state.items.map((item,i) => 
                    <li className='list-group-item' key={i} data-id={item.id}>{item.name}
                         <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, item.id)}>X</button>
                    </li>
               )}
           </ul>
        ) 
   }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1151/).

Comment: Thanks for a complete sample of a working React component to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Mayid is correct that it is not good to declare or bind functions in render method if the function is passed into other component as a props.

Unfortunately currentTarget didn't work for me.

I have used getAttribute function of event.target. This doesn't cause unnecessary rerenders.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handleClick = (event) => {    
    console.log(event.target.getAttribute('index'))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button index="1" onClick={this.handleClick}>   
        Click me
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is a running sample;

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        items: [{
          id: 0,
          name: "Buy milk"
        }, {
          id: 1,
          name: "Write unit tests"
        }, {
          id: 2,
          name: "Cook a meal"
        }]
      }
      this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick(value) {
      console.log(`${value} clicked`);
    }

    renderTodos() {
      return this.state.items.map((item, idx) => {
        return ( < li className = 'list-group-item'
          key = {
            idx
          } > {
            item.name
          } < button onClick = {
            () => this.handleClick(item.id)
          } > X < /button>
        </li >
        )
      })
    }
    render() {
        return ( < ul id = "todo" > {
            this.renderTodos()
          } < /ul>
    ) 
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/ > ,
          document.getElementById('react_example')
        );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="react_example"></div>
</body>

</html>
```