# Getting id from an event handler that was passed to a button component in React?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an App component that renders a MenuBar component. In that MenuBar, I render ListItems (from material-ui) and pass the following as a prop:

```
    onClick = (e) => {

    const id = e.target.id;
    console.log(id);
    console.log('called');
}
```

the MenuBar component:

```
    render() {
    const onClick = this.props.onClick;
    const titles = ["Home", "About", "Docket", "Polls", "News"];
    const listItems = titles.map(title =>
        <ListItem button id={title} onClick={onClick} key={title}>
            <ListItemText primary={title} />
        </ListItem>);
    return (
        <List
            component="ul"
            className="menu-bar">
            {listItems}
        </List>
    );
}
```

I want to use this title, which I try to retrieve from the event, so that I can render a Home component, or About component, etc, depending on which ListItem is selected. But when I run this and click randomly on some of the ListItems in my browser, the title is only logged to the console sometimes (seemingly randomly). What is the best way for me to access which ListItem was selected, or why is the console logging the title only sometimes?

Here is what I get in the browser console:

Docket

called

called

Polls

called

News

called

Comment: are you  looking for a solution like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n21hta ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pass id through on click react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818569/pass-id-through-on-click-react-js)

Comment: @Jayavel 's solution also worked

Comment: @Stevie glad it helped ! can i post this as answer, please accept it and upvote it if it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you don't consistently get `id` is that the html element triggering the click event is not always what you think. Please see [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/54zv3844rx) for an example. When you click on any of the `ListItem`, sometimes you get (if you click to the left of where the letter is, based on my trials):

```
 <div class="MuiButtonBase-root-1883 MuiListItem-root-1871 MuiListItem-default-1874 MuiListItem-gutters-1879 MuiListItem-button-1880" tabindex="0" role="button" id="a">...</div>
```

where the `id` is present. But other times you get:

```
<span class="MuiTypography-root-1892 MuiTypography-subheading-1899 MuiListItemText-primary-1889">a</span>
```

where the `id` is missing.

A solution to this is to pass `title` directly to the `onClick` function:

```
 <ListItem button id={title} onClick={() => onClick(title)}>
     ...
 </ListItem>
```

Accordingly, the `onClick` function should be updated as follows:

```
onClick = (title) => {
    console.log(title);
    console.log('called');
}
```

Comment: Your solution solved the issue, thank you. For anyone else, when you use this solution, in your handler function you should log the event e, not e.target.id or e.target.title. The returned event is simply the title you passed to onClick={() => onClick(title)}

Comment: @Stevie, I've updated the post to include the change to the handler function. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Stevie, if this has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

***current***Target is what worked it for me. (instead of just target)

I've read elsewhere that maybe MUI is resulting in unexpected behavior. Similar to what Claire Lin stated, in the Material UI List (and for me, it was nested in a MUI Drawer as well), when clicking on a button, the actual target was different from what I expected. The solution I found is to use the following:

Try **e.currentTarget.getAttribute('value')** , where "value" is data placed on the ListItem.
Here's how I added it.  See "value" being assigned, and then logged below in the onClick.  (...I tried to remove most of the extra code, but there is still a bit of superfluous code in there just bc it provides context.)

```
return (
 //removed extra code for brevity 
 <Drawer
    anchor={'left'}
    open={drawerOpen}
    onClose={toggleDrawerOpen(false)}
  >
    <List>
      {itemsList.map((item, index) => {
        const { text, icon, id } = item
        return (
          <ListItem
            button
            key={id}
            value={index} // <<<< HERE!!! 
            onClick={(e) => {
              console.log(e.currentTarget.getAttribute('value')) // <<<< HERE!!! 

              setDrawerOpen(false)
            }}
          >
            {icon && <ListItemIcon>{icon}</ListItemIcon>}
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        )
      })}
    </List>
  </Drawer>
```

...Again, I used "value" and assigned it the "index".
**current**Target is the trick.