# Is there a way to pass id of input tag as a onclick function parameter without actually writing the id value in JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am working on a react application. I have several inputs for advanced search that uses the same function to determine the onclick action. Is there a way to pass the id of the input tag as a onclick function parameter without actually writing the id value in JSX?

So I wanted to make writing my code faster in input code in JSX. By simply copy-pasting the function parameters all the way down

```
          <label className="container">
            <p>First name</p>
            <input
              id="check-firstname"
              type="checkbox"
              onClick={() => inputAction(id)} // it doesnt work i tried
                 // i would be happy if i can copy paste this same in 20  other places
            />
            <span className="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </li>
```

I know this is the traditional way of doing it

```
<li className="search-list-off">
          <label className="container">
            <p>First name</p>
            <input
              id="check-firstname"
              type="checkbox"
              onClick={() => inputAction('check-firstname')} // i dont wanted to write this for each ids
            />
            <span className="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </li>
```

Its ok if there isnt a solution, you can help me suggesting the best thing to do

Comment: Well a simple way is just to make an array of all the `id`s and render it with a `.map`. That way you don't have to copy paste all the JSX, and you'll have access to the id value to use in both the `id` prop _and_ the `onClick` prop

Comment: I don't know reactjs very well, but taking my knowledge from javascript, would something like `onClick={e => inputAction(e.target.id)}` work? ... edit: perhaps [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39818569/pass-id-through-on-click-react-js) will help

Comment: @Bravo yes that works

Comment: ``` <li className="search-list-off">
          <label className="container">
            <p>First name</p>
            <input
              id="check-firstname"
              type="checkbox"
              onClick={e => inputAction(e)}
            />
            <span className="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </li>```

Comment: Or you can make this element as it's own component that takes an a prop of the data including the object. That way this child component has access to it's own `id` and can emit events as needed including passing this `id` to the parent component.

Comment: I did this at first. but I wanted to incorporate certain animations which made it hard for me to manage each input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
<li className="search-list-off">
          <label className="container">
            <p>First name</p>
            <input
              id="check-firstname"
              type="checkbox"
              onClick={(e) => inputAction(e.target.id)} // i dont wanted to write this for each ids
            />
            <span className="checkmark"></span>
          </label>
        </li>
```

Comment: i would suggest to use `name` attribute and pass the event to the function, this will makes easy to check the checkbox checked or not more easy.

Comment: @AkhilAravind spot on. But I just wanted to demonstrate you can pass the id using ```event.target.id```.

Comment: @FaizHameed check this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-worker-3fw3z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark